# Send and Get payload in express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Now I send data to express server as query param. But, I instead send the data to express server as payload.
How do I send payload data to express server? And how do I get the payload data from express server? Can anyone clear my doubts?

Here is my code,

```
// http request code

var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('post','localhost:9090/putData');
http.onload=function(){
    if (this.status >=200 && this.status <300){
        console.log(this.response);
    }
};
var payload = {
    data: 'Something'
}
http.send(payload);

// server.js

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use('/putData', function(req, res){
     console.log(req.body); // empty object printed
})
```

What's wrong in my code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; if you're just asking how to deal with things like JSON in a POST request, pretty much any Express tutorial will cover this since it's so common. If you're asking how to send it, it depends on how you *want* to send it. If it's a browser, this is also well-documented in any number of tutorials. If not, you'd have to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to reference 'body' from the request object.  Depending on the type, you can deserialize it with a parser.  I use the npm package 'body-parser' to deserialize my objects to json.  Set up the body parser in the express middleware as shown below

```
app.use(bodyparser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Then you can use the req.body object in your following requests`

```
app.get('getBody', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
   res.status(200);
});`
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @franzke. I edited my question. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Make sure you install the package 'body-parser' from npm and then include it with a require statement before using it var bodyparser = require('body-parser');.  Also, the client may need to set the Content-Type header to application/json to ensure the server knows how to read the body.